# Give an example of a closed subset of ($\mathbb{C},d$)

Tags: complex-analysis

Give an example of a closed subset of ($\mathbb{C},d$) where $d$ is the standard metric $d(z,w)=|z-w|$ for $z,w \in \mathbb{C}$

I know that a a subset is closed if $(\mathbb{C},d)$ without the subset is open

Answer (score 1):

How about a singleton $\{a\}$? Or better still, the empty set $\emptyset$.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, then using what you know, what would be an example of an open set $U$? Then $\Bbb C\smallsetminus U$ is closed.

Answer (score 1):

$\emptyset$, a singleton point set, the set of finite points and the whole space are all closed set. A singleton point set, the set of finite points are closed as the space is $T_1$. Or you can take any subset $A$, take the closure of $A$, then you can get a new closed subset.